# Elasticsearch pagination multisearch API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query using "MultiSearch API", my queries is like this:

```
{"index" : "my-index-01", "type": "my-type-01"}
{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"house","fields":["name", "title"]}}}
{"index" : "my-index-02", "type": "my-type-02"}
{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"c","fields":["name","title"]}}}
{"index" : "my-index-03", "type": "my-type-03"}
{"query":{"multi_match":{"query":"c","fields":["name"]}}}
```

I would like to know if is possible to use "scroll" in Multisearch API (in each query) or I can only use from/size?

Which is the best way to paginate using multisearch API?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch **Multisearch API** Doesn't support **Scroll API** yet.
[Github Thread](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18454)

It is better to use `from & size` for your purpose.